# Java Applet is undefined

Tags: javascript, java, html, applet, zebra-printers

I have this *jzebra* applet that I need to do some client side ticket printing.

This is the applets html definition:

```html
<applet id="jzebra" name="jzebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="../../../../../../web/org.openbravo.howtos/lib/jzebra.jar" 
  width="10px" height="10px">
```

The `function` I call in the form button is this:

```js
function printDocument() {

  var applet = document.jzebra;
  var frm = document.frmMain;
  var url = frm.elements["inpftpOBDir"].value;
  var file ="0.txt";
  var archivo = url + "/" + file;
  if (applet != null) {
  var printname = frm.elements["inpPrinterName"].value;
  var indice = frm.inpPrinterSelected.selectedIndex;
  var printselected = frm.inpPrinterSelected.options[indice].text;
        alert(printname);
        alert(printselected);
        if(printselected == ""){
           // printname = "zebra"
           //alert('Default : ' + printname);
           applet.findPrinter(printname);
           monitorFinding();
        } else {
           //alert('Selected : ' + printselected);
           applet.findPrinter(printname);
           monitorFinding();
        }
        alert('File : ' + archivo);
        // applet.findPrinter(printname);
        applet.appendFile(archivo);

        // Send characters/raw commands to printer
        applet.print();
          alert('The document was sent to the printer.');
   }
}
```

I checked the console and there is a definition of applet, but when it reaches `applet.findPrinter(printname)`, just explodes because `applet.findPrinter` is not a function.

Has anyone faced this struggle before? I have seen that there is a little gray square in the top left corner of my page. When I `hover` on it, it displays "`undefined`".

Comment: Thanks for not helping, please do not return to this

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with a very complex solution, having to use jnlp. I will post my code later for references, if anyone else find similar problems.